# Vector resize/assign not adding default value

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have a class which has a string vector as a variable and a constructor which takes inputs to set the size of this vector.  The only problem is the default value is NOT being set at all for the elements in the vector.  What's wrong here?  Tried both resize and assign but just end up with blanks each time.

Class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Lab
{
private:
    vector<string> station;
    int id;

public:
    Lab()
    {
        station[0] = "Empty";
        id = 0;
    };
    Lab(int ID, int size)
    {
        station.assign(size, "Empty");
        id = ID;
    };
    Lab(const Lab& labcpy)
    {
        station.resize(labcpy.station.size());
        id = labcpy.id;
    };
```

Main where the size of the vector is set:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "lab.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream labnumber_file(argv[1]);
    vector<Lab> lab_v;

    int labnum;
    int usernum;
    while(!labnumber_file.eof())
    {
        labnumber_file >> labnum;
        labnumber_file >> usernum;

        lab_v.push_back(Lab(labnum, usernum));
    }
```

Comment: have you implemented an assignment operator for Lab ?

Comment: Your default constructor is buggy. `station` should be initialized to accept 1 element first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
station.resize(labcpy.station.size());
```

with

```
station = labcpy.station;
```

in your copy constructor. You are only allocating space, but are not copying data. Just use the vector's assignment operator to copy data. It will also handle the re-sizing.

On a side note: 
You might want to avoid using array operators[] as they do not do bounds checking.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks! I guess the default copy constructor wasn't ideal in Eclipse linux.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `push_back` uses your copy constructor, but your copy constructor doesn't copy anything into `station`.

Since your data members are safe to copy, just use the default copy constructor. Remove the copy constructor you defined.

The rule of three is that if you need to define a destructor, you also need to define a copy constructor and the assignment operator. However, since you do not need to define a destructor, the rule does not apply to the `Lab` class.

Comment: I got rid of my copy constructor and did the declarations as Christian said above but still end up with blanks instead of it saying empty...

Answer (score 2):

You don't copy anything in your copy constructor, you just resize the vector `station` without copying any values into it. Just use `station`'s copy constructor with `labcpy.station` as argument. But you know what, you don't need to implement any copy constructor anyway, since the compiler generated one works perfectly here (as it just copies `station` and `id`).

And also your default constructor invokes undefined behaviour, since you access `station[0]` without `station` having any elements.

And last but not least, you should rather use initialization lists, instead of doing a default constructions followed by assignments. (And don't put semicolons after function definitions.)

```
class Lab
{
private:
    vector<string> station;
    int id;

public:
    Lab()
        : station(1, "Empty"), id(0)
    {
    }
    Lab(int ID, int size)
        : station(size, "Empty"), id(ID)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten how to write constructors properly.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
    Lab(const Lab& labcpy)
    {
         station.resize(labcpy.station.size());
         id = labcpy.id;
    };
```

here you resize the vector but you dont add any values to it. So if you use this to copy a default constructed `Lab` you will just be changing the size, but not assigning any string value to the new elements (which are probably just initialised as empty strings). Secondly you should also implement an assignment operator